# Can't get hot shoe flash to fire on Fujifilm Fine Pix

Tags: flash, fujifilm

When my grandfather passed away I received a achiever auto thyristor 260T. I cannot seem to get the flash to go off when I take a picture. I made sure it was set up the best I could but it still won't take a picture. I have a Fujifilm fine pix sl. I was wondering if there is something I have to set on my camera or if I set the flash up incorrectly? My brothers 18th birthday is coming and I would like to get some quality photos by then, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Bad news: the [botzilla table of sync voltages](http://www.botzilla.com/photo/strobeVolts.html) reports that the sync voltage of the 260T is 220V.  The Fuji X hotshoe, as far as is known, [has a limit of 50V](http://www.fujixseries.com/discussion/comment/4383#Comment_4383).  Hopefully the flash simply doesn't work, and you haven't fried your Fuji X's hotshoe.

If you *have* to use this flash, I'd suggest getting a [Wein SafeSync](http://www.weinproducts.com/safesyncs.htm).

It would probably be better to get a modern digital-era flash that's within the voltage limits for your camera, and that offers TTL capability.  Maybe [a Nissin i40](http://www.nissindigital.com/i40.html) when it becomes available?